# Minimum and Maximum of $f(x,y)=\sin(y-x)-\sin(y)+\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus

> I need to identify the minimum and maximum of $f(x,y)=\sin(y-x)-\sin(y)+\sin(x)$ with $0 \le x \le y \le 2\pi$.

First I calculated
$$
\nabla f(x,y)=(\cos(x)-\cos(y-x),\cos(y-x)-\cos(y)).
$$
The gradient gets zero in both of the components if and only if:
$\cos(x)-\cos(y-x)=0$ and $\cos(y-x)-\cos(y)=0$.

From this one can conclude that $\cos(x)=\cos(y)$ and this is only true if and only if $x=\pm y$.

But that's a very confusing result because in GeoGebra3D I saw that the maximum of the function (where $0 \le x \le y \le 2\pi$)  is at $(2 \pi/3,4 \pi/3)$.

What am I doing wrong?

I hope someone can help me. Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure that $ \cos x = \cos y \Leftrightarrow x = \pm y$? EG What is $ \cos 2 \pi / 3, \cos 4\pi / 3 $?

Comment: Here is one possible value: $\cos x = \cos (y-x) \implies y = 2x$. Plug in the second, $\cos x = \cos 2x \implies 2\pi -x = 2x$ so $x = \frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

$$f=\sin(y-x)-\sin(y)+\sin(x)$$

---

$$\partial_xf=-\cos(y-x)+\cos(x)$$
$$\partial_yf=\cos(y-x)-\cos(y)$$

---

$$\begin{cases}
\cos(y-x)=\cos(x) \\
\cos(y-x)=\cos(y)
\end{cases}$$
say for the first one, the obvious solutions are:
$$y=0,y=2x$$ but any multiple of $2\pi$ would also work, giving $y=2k\pi\{k\in\mathbb Z\}$ but also $y=2x-2k\pi\{k\in\mathbb Z\}$. So you have to be careful with these as well

---

Just for completion, the second one would give:
$$x=2k\pi$$
$$x=2y-2k\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically speaking, $\dfrac{4\pi}{3} = 2\pi - \dfrac{2\pi}{3} = -\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ .

Geometrically in the circle we can have : $2\pi - x = -x$ $\to$ $\cos(2\pi - x) = \cos(-x) = \cos(x)$, unless you got a spiral that has it's radius increased linearly with the angle, that statement doesn't hold geometrically ($2\pi - x \neq -x$).

So you have to be careful about making asumption of $\cos(x) = \cos(y) \to x = \pm y$ , you have to understand it geometrically too.